# Log table with millions of rows. Now, what?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a Log table with millions of rows. I'm thinking about separating the data into multiple tables (i.e. LoginHistory, ExceptionHistroy, PaymentProcessingHistory, etc.) What is the term used when taking a large table with many rows (not Columns) and creating multiple tables?

My current Log table schema resembles: LogID, LogMessage, LogReason, LoggedBy, LoggedOn, etc.

The problem is I'm putting too many things in one table, I think? Perhaps the table is too generic?

Thanks

Comment: Jason, why can't I say Thanks in my question?

Comment: you can.  I've just gotten in the habit of pulling it out when I make a separate edit on a question, as per this topic on meta (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3):

It is called data partitioning.

Answer (score 3):

[Sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharding) is the term de jour. From the link:

> Horizontal partitioning is a database design principle whereby rows of a database table are held separately, rather than splitting by columns (as for normalization). Each partition forms part of a **shard**, which may in turn be located on a separate database server or physical location.

Comment: Very Interesting! This might be the solution; however, I feel that my table is too generic? Any more clever ideas?

Comment: +1 The concept of sharding is new to me, I knew about the idea of horizontal partitioning, but I didn't know the actual name of "sharding". Something interesting from the Wikipedia entry to keep in mind, is that you should try to create your shards in such a way that each shard has a meaning or context (in  the article the given example is to have a shard for american customers and other shard for european customers).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Abel. With sharding, am I able to select only from a specified partition? For example, the ExceptionHistory partition or the LoginHistory partition of the Log table.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be looking at **horizontal partitioning**.  Horizontal partitioning is more or less a subset of sharding.

For more details on horizontal partitioning, here's the wikipedia link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29

You didn't mention which DB technology you use, but here are some technical links that can get you going with partitioning your data:

[IBM DB2 partitioning](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2help/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/c0004885.htm)
[MySQL partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)
[Oracle partitioning](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/options/partitioning/index.htm)
[SQL Server partitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx)
[PostgreSQL partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-partitioning.html)
[Sybase ASE 15.0 partitioning](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1036923)

Comment: I would prefer not to split my table into partitions. I'm actually looking into splitting one table into many tables. I'm sorry if I didn't articulate my question correctly. I'm wondering what that is called when you go from one table to many tables? Thanks