# mysql can denormalization improve the performance of my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a legacy DB which uses a table similar to this structure:

```
orders
    id, buyer_id, product
```

the table saves the product as text instead of referencing to the products table (which exists). The person who setup the table explained his reasoning:

The products are quite unique. i.e. There are only 2 or 3 buyers for each different product. The product table is therefore almost as big as the orders table. He wants to avoid a join to speed up the queries on the orders table.

Does this actually improve performance so it's worth having denormalized data for the following usecase:

```
buyers table with 10.000 entries
products table with 40.000.000 entries
orders (buyer_product) table with 40.000.000 entries
```

1. Normalized:
   SELECT * FROM buyer_product 
   JOIN products ON products.id = buyer_product.product_id
   LIMIT 1000;
2. Denormalized (product saved as text instead of product_id)
   SELECT * FROM buyer_product  LIMIT 1000;

EDIT:
For some weird reason 1 even seems to be faster:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE bp.buyer_id, product.name
FROM buyer_product bp
JOIN products ON bp.product_id = products.id 
ORDER BY bp.id
LIMIT 1000000;
```

query time 0.250 sec

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE bp.buyer_id, bp.product 
FROM buyer_product bp 
ORDER BY bp.id 
LIMIT 1000000;
```

query time 0.268 sec

Comment: This might can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102590/what-exactly-does-database-normalization-do

Comment: Of course #2 will be faster, it's just way more harder to maintain integrity. Of course you could have a Foreign Key to the procuct name instead of the id.

Comment: Why don't you test it and see for yourself?

Comment: Both qeuries should also use a ORDER BY id ASC to make sure the results stay the same

Comment: @RaymondNijland done

Comment: @Shadow added results to question

Comment: @dnoeth for some weird reason #1 is slightly faster

Comment: Could be less I/O is required when normalized.  Anyway, you have your answer.

Comment: Your select lists are different in the queries.

Comment: @Shadow that is on purpose. #1 selects from the joined table. #2 uses the additional (redundant) column product (varchar) instead of the reference