# What is the point of a junction table

Tags: database-design, relational-database, junction-table

I've been reading up on normalization and relationships and am curious -- is the only point of a junction table to store attributes that don't make sense in either of the parent tables?

For example, if you have a Chat and Users table, and a chat can have many users and visa versa, couldn't you just have a one-to-many relationship on both tables without a junction table?

That is, couldn't you say that a chat has many users and that a user has many chats?

Why would you have to create a table such as ChatUsers and then say that a chats has many chatUsers and that a user has many ChatUsers?

The only reason I can think of is that you want to add attributes like number of undread messages per chat, or notification settings, which only make sense in a ChatUsers table.

If this is not the case, and you don't need to add anything, does the concept of many-to-many even make sense? wouldn't it just be easier to think of it as two one-to-many relationships?

Comment: What is the 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? Where/how are you 1st stuck following what published information modelling & DB design method?

Comment: [What exactly does database normalization do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1102590/3404097) [What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/246701/3404097)

Answer (score 3):

The use of the junction table takes your data to its lowest possible normalised level, it should be used where there is something that could be duplicated across multiple entires such as a date or a time.

I cannot think of a specific example with a Chat and Chat User table, but one ive come across a lot is in relation to addresses.

As individuals both you and myself could live at the same address, but at different times. It wouldnt be appropriate to hold a date of when I lived at an address in a user table (as I could live at multiple addresses). It also wouldnt be appropriate to record a date in the address table (as this could lead to multiple address lines), as such you should end up with tables with the following design and data.

User_Table

| User_Id | User_Name |
| --- | --- |
| U1 | John Smith |
| U2 | Jane Smith |
| U3 | Rebecca Smith |

Address_Table

| Address_Id | Address |
| --- | --- |
| AD1 | 1 High Street |
| AD2 | 2 High Street |
| AD3 | 3 High Street |
| AD4 | 4 High Street |

Address_History_Table

| Add_His_ID | User_Id | Address_Id | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AH1 | U1 | AD1 | 01/09/2000 | 01/01/2019 |
| AH2 | U1 | AD2 | 02/01/2019 | 31/08/2022 |
| AH3 | U2 | AD1 | 02/01/2019 |  |
| AH4 | U3 | AD2 | 01/08/1965 | 31/08/2022 |

In this example U1 (John Smith) and U2 (Jane Smith) have both lived at address AD1(1 High Street) but not at the same time. In this example Jane moved in (02/01/2019) the day after John moved out (02/01/2019).

U1 (John Smith), then moved into AD2 (2 High Street) from the 02/01/2019 with no end date. U3 (Rebecca Smith) lived in this address already (start_date of 01/08/1965) and lived there until 31/08/2022.

From this we can identify that John and Jane havent lived together, while John and Rebecca did (From the 02/01/2019 to 31/08/2022).

The use of the junction table will very much depend on your data. In your chat example if two users were in the same chat for the exact same time, could lead to a duplication if a time for example was recorded.

A juntion table can sometimes just be three columns

- Primary Key of the table
- Foreign Key of the user table
- Foreign Key of the chat table

The junction table would then just be used to denote which chat linked to which user, and dosent need to contain any other information.

Comment: Thank you for your example! It makes a lot of sense. I just want to clarify though — this agrees with what I said about only needing a junction table if there are attributes that don’t fit in either parent table right? I.e., if I just needed a users current address and no time stamps, I could just have it so that a user can have many addresses (if a user has multiple homes) and that an address can have multiple users (people living together), with no disadvantage right?